# File sharing user limits

Tags: operating-systems, network-shares, file-sharing, shared-folders

Each OS has a limit to the number of users that can access a computers shared folders at one time. XP has 10, 7 has 20. At one time I thought I saw a site where the limit for most OS's were listed. I've googled and googled and googled but can not find a list.

Does anyone know where to find such a list? Or possibly do you know the limits for many OS's?

I am interested in

- MacOS
- OS X
- Linux (Samba or something like that... not familiar with Linux)
- Windows Server 2003
- Windows Server 2008
- Windows Server 2012
- (?) Windows 8
- 7....20
- XP...10
- Windows 2000

Answer (score 6):

Linux limits are [defined in the smb.conf file](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#MAXCONNECTIONS):

```
Example: max connections = 10
```

Mac [OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA21045) has a limit of 10 (unless you have the server version):

> In Mac OS X version 10.0 or later, Personal File Sharing is designed
>   to serve a maximum of 10 users. If you need to connect more users at
>   once, you should upgrade to Unlimited-Client version of Mac OS X
>   Server (http://www.apple.com/server/).

Windows [Non-Server versions](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/local-area-network-wi-fi-wireless,3020-2.html):

- 5 users: Windows XP Home, Vista Starter/Home Basic
- 10 users: WindowsNT, 2000, XP Professional, Vista Home Premium/Business/Enterprise/ -
  Ultimate
- 20 users: Windows 7, [Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/network-sharing/3782-max-incoming-connections-windows-8-a.html)

Windows [Server versions](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9a70af9e-c97f-4728-b195-e178a942450d/shared-folder-connection-limit-on-windows-2003-server): (whether [2003](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/2003_Server/Q_23414857.html) or newer)

> ... default settings for connection is Unlimited
>
> Your connection Limit Depends only of how many CALs you are added to
>   your license.
>        Example: If you have Windows 2003 Server and 25 Per User or Per Device CALs you have a limit of 25 users or devices connected to your
>   Share Drive.

Comment: Windows 10 Pro: 20

Answer (score 2):

Run this command on CMD and check max supported connection.

```
net config server
```